# Gmapping with V-REP

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, vrep, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm doing a course project whose goal is to build a SLAM simulation with ROS and V-REP.

I'm new to ROS and V-REP and I'd like some help from you guys.
Here is what I did:

1. I created a scene with a p3dx robot in V-REP.
2. I publish Twist message on ROS to control the motion of the robot in V-REP.
3. V-REP is publishing 3 frames to ROS:
   "odom": the fixed world coordinate;
   "base_link": the robot coordinate;
   "laser": the laser sensor coordinate.
   Also, V-REP is publishing laserScan data as well.
4. I run gmapping node, subscribing to the LaserScan data.
5. I run RVIZ and changed the fixed frame to /map, so that I can visualize the ongoing mapping while the robot moves in V-REP.

Here comes the question, I'm getting a error message for the global state in RVIZ:
"Fixed Frame [map] does not exist"
How should i fix this?
I assume that I need to define a new frame corresponding to "map" but how am I supposed to do it? Just create a new coordinate and add a tf between "map" and "odom"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309671/gmapping-with-v-rep/) by [mcai](https://answers.ros.org/users/38529/mcai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You will have to create a new frame called map. So that all your map data is attached to that transform frame.

Have you had a look at this ros [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29)?

It shows you how to add a frame in c++. If you are using Python look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28Python%29)

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) with karma: 91 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0